# Why isn't the mean() function in R giving me the right result?

Tags: r

I've been practicing basics in R (3.6.3) and I'm stuck trying to understand this problem for hours already. This was the exercise:

*Step 1: Generate sequence of data between 1 and 3 of total length 100; #use the jitter function (with a large factor) to add noise to your data
Step 2: Compute the vector of rolling averages roll.mean with the average of 5 consecutive points. This vector has only 96 averages.
Step 3: add the vector of these averages to your plot
Step 4: generalize step 2 and step 3 by making a function with parameters consec (default=5) and y.*

```
y88 = seq(1,3,0.02)
y = jitter(y88, 120, set.seed(1))
y = y[-99] # removed one guy so y can have 100 elements, as asked

roll.meanT = rep(0,96)
for (i in 1:length(roll.meanT)) # my 'reference i' is roll.mean[i], not y[i]
{
roll.meanT[i] = (y[i+4]+y[i+3]+y[i+2]+y[i+1]+y[i])/5  
}

plot(y)
lines(roll.meanT, col=3, lwd=2)
```

This produced this plot:
[image]

Then, I proceed to generalize using a function (it asks me to generalize steps 2 and 3, so the data creation step was ignored) and I consider y to remain constant):

```
fun50 = function(consec=5,y)
{
  roll.mean <- rep(NA,96) # Apparently, we just leave NA's as NA's, since lenght(y) is always greater than lenght(roll.means)
  for (i in 1:96)
  {
    roll.mean[i] <- mean(y[i:i+consec-1]) # Using mean(), I'm able to generalize.
  } 
  plot(y)
  lines(roll.mean, col=3, lwd=2)
}
```

Which gave me a completely different plot:

[image]

When I manually try too see if mean(y[1:5]) produces the right mean, it does. I know I could have already used the mean() function in the first part, but I would really like to get the same results using (y[i+4]+y[i+3]+y[i+2]+y[i+1]+y[i])/5 or mean(y[1:5],......).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the line

```
    roll.mean[i] <- mean(y[i:i+consec-1]) # Using mean(), I'm able to generalize.
```

I believe your intention is to grab the values with indices i to (i+consec-1).  Unfortunately for you - the `:` operator takes precedence over arithmetic operations.

```
> 1:1+5-1  #(this is what your code would do for i=1, consec=5)
[1] 5
> (1:1)+5-1 # this is what it's actually doing for you
> 5
> 2:2+5-1 #(this is what your code would do for i=2, consec=5)
[1] 6
> 3:3+5-1 #(this is what your code would do for i=3, consec=5)
[1] 7
> 3:(3+5-1) #(this is what you want your code to do for i=3, consec=5)
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

so to fix - just add some parenthesis

```
roll.mean[i] <- mean(y[i:(i+consec-1)]) # Using mean(), I'm able to generalize.
```

Comment: One thing to note - you might consider looking at the previous values instead of the values ahead of the current observation.  Typically things like rolling means are used for smoothing time series types of things and it's not necessarily 'fair' to consider the future observations to smooth your current value.